# using Parseval's identity to estimate the value of $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, self-learning, parsevals-identity

There is a problem with two parts; The first part is asking to find Fourier series for $f(x)=|\sin(x)|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. And the second part wants to estimate the following using Parseval's identity:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}
$$

I'm not sure it is necessary to use the answer of the first part or not. I don't know what to do!

**The first part answer:**

 $$\forall n, b_n=0$$.

$$
a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sin(x)|dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x)dx=\frac{-2}{\pi}\cos(x)]_0^\pi=\frac{-2}{\pi}(-1-1)=\frac{4}{\pi}
$$

\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sin(x)|\cos(nx) dx
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi [\sin(x+nx)+\sin(x-nx)]\\ =\frac{1}{\pi}[\frac{-\cos((n+1)x)}{2(n+1)}+\frac{-\cos((1-n)x)}{2(1-n)}]_0^\pi \\
a_n=\frac{-1}{\pi}(\frac{\cos(n\pi)+1}{n^2-1})
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you do the first part? If so, please, include your work in the post.

Comment: Hint: check your answers for $a_n$ in the first part of the problem, you should for instance have $a_1=0$.

Comment: Did I integrate correctly?! I became a bit confused... When we have $n=1$, the $n-1=0$ and the fraction $\frac{1}{n-1}$ can not be defined :|

Comment: Almost, the factors 2 in the denominator should not be there. Now work out the value for $a_n$ by distinguishing even and odd values. Just plugin some numbers n=2,3,4,.. and check that the pattern you find is also correct for $n=1$.

Comment: `\Sigma` $\to$ `\sum`, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier series of the function $f(x)$ is given by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n x}
$$
with 
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi d x~f(x) e^{-\imath n x}
$$
In the case $f(x) = |\sin x |$, this results in
$$
c_n = 2 \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^\pi d x~\sin x e^{-\imath n x} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -\frac{2}{\pi (n^2-1)} & \text{for $n$ even}\\ 0 & \text{for $n$ odd} \end{array} \right.
$$
Using Parsifal's identity we have
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi d x ~ |\sin x|^2 = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Since $c_{n} = c_{-n}$ the sum on the left hand side can be rewritten as
$$
c_0^2 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n^2 = \frac{1}{2}
$$
From which it follows that with $c_0=\frac{2}{\pi}$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2} - c_0^2\right) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{\pi^2}
$$
Using the result we found for $c_n$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{2 n - 1}^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{2 n}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{2 n}^2 = \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 n^2 -1)^2}
$$
and therefore we finally obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 n^2 -1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{\pi^2} \right) = \frac{\pi^2-8}{16}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess I did it!

I want to know the value of:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{((2n)^2-1)^2}
$$
So let $m=2n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2-1)^2}$. 
From the first part and Parseval's identity,
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin^2(x)dx=\frac{16}{2\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{((-1)^m+1)^2}{(m^2-1)^2}
$$
since $m=2n$,
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Good thinking, but taking the square of a function does not mean that the coefficients in its cosine series are also squared. So you will need to rewrite the sum $\sum \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)}$ in terms that are easier. This is possible because you can factories the denominator.

Comment: From the wikipedia page of Parseval's identity:" the identity asserts that the sum of the squares of the Fourier coefficients of a function is equal to the integral of the square of the function"

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too hasty and misread what you did, I actually solved this in a different way. Parsifal's identity is based on the complex series, rather then the cosine series. This means it will result in $|a_0|^2 + 2 \sum_i |a_i|^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int dx \sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. This gives $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2-8}{16}$. Also the reformulation of the sum in terms of $m$ is not correct, you only should sum over even values of $m$.

Comment: but $m=2n$ and it is even!

Comment: I know that is why you mean, but what you write is $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(1^2-1)^2} $ + $\frac{1}{(2^2-1)^2}+  \frac{1}{(3^2-1)^2 } + \dots$ is something different. You can write it for instance as $\sum_{m ~\text{even} > 0}$ .